# Expectation of ratio of normal and root chi-square

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, expected-value

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3, X_4$ be i.i.d $N(0,1)$ random variables. What is the expectation of $$(X_1-X_2+X_3)/\sqrt {X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2+X_4^2}$$?
I know how to obtain t-distribution but I wonder if the above can be written as one since the terms in the numberator and denominator may not be independent.

Comment: You mean that $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $0$ because the variable you are considering is symmetric. [ You can 
write the expectation as an integral w.r.t. the joint distribution of the $X_i$'s. Since this joint distribution is symmetric we see that the required expectation is $0$].

Comment: Agreed sir but only two such variables cancel out and the one with $X_3$ remains.

Comment: @Jor_El You have to use the fact that $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ and $(-X_1,-X_2,-X_3,-X_4)$ have the same joint distribution.